# devise model with acts_as_taggable_on doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a project that has users and users each have a list of skills, presented as tags using acts_as_taggable_on. When I try to sign up, it tells me that there is no method each for the string I have inputted as skills. In other parts of the site where I use acts_as_taggable_on, without devise, it works

The sign up form on reload: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWnXL.png

The sign up form after completion: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1UF8.png

The error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKtqU.png